# How can I see a value on the spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

My question is: I am using spinner on my android app. However, I can't see the default value shown on the spinner, at all. I can select elements but I can't see any text on the spinner. It seems like the value is hidden and doesn't show anything, just the spinner itself and drop down arrow.

```
mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllBusinessCards();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    contactSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contactSpinner);

    contactSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    fillData();


}
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The planet is " +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}

private void fillData() {



/*Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only the 'colourName' column in this case) */

String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.getKeyTitle() }; 
/* and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just the textView 'tvDBViewRow' from our new db_view_row.xml layout above) */
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvDBViewRow};

/* Now create a simple cursor adapter.. */ 
SimpleCursorAdapter colourAdapter =
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.db_view_row, cursor, from, to);

/* and assign it to our Spinner widget */ 
contactSpinner.setAdapter(colourAdapter);
//contactSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
contactSpinner.setSelection(0);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what it looks like when the spinner is up?

Comment: it is exactly the same as when you view it in the layout design model. gray spinner no text written on it plain. when I click on it it shows the list and I can click any of them. this closes the list how ever I can still only see the spinner itself no text.

Comment: are you doing `contactSpinner.setDropDownResource(R.id.spinner)` ?

Comment: No I am not. Because I am fetching the items from a database. So In this case do I need to do that?

Comment: Yes, you are defining what the item looks like when it is retrieved.  Try ` adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Comment: No luck :( it I am using custom layout for the dropdown. I jsut added the code up there. if you can have a look. As I said there is no problem with the selecting items. it works absolutely fine. the only issue is that when I select an item I cant see the selected item on the snipper I cant see anything actually not even default one. no text at all.

Comment: If you're using something custom, you need to make sure you're doing everything the default uses.  I can't help you if you don't post more code.

Comment: I added all the code. please have a look if you need I can put the xml part as well. Thank you

Comment: I don't see anywhere within your implemented interface where it actually sets the value to the spinner.  Perhaps you should try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call spinner.setSelection to set the current state of the 
spinner to whatever you want. And that definitely works

```
spinner.setSelection(0);
```

but you must also call
setDropDownViewResource()

let say

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: When I add this code: contactSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); it is not recognized method at all. and gives error.

Comment: you need to add to the adapter not to the spinner

Comment: I did add it now in the adapter :) because I am usin custom layout. therefore instead of doing adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 I did adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.db_view_row) but now when I keep my finger on the snipper I can see the selected item. when I release my finger I cant see what is on the snipper again gray color no text at all..
R.layout.);

Comment: it is solved the text color was the same as spinner thats why it wasnt seen :) thanks